# Open info window on non-click event

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am working on a map using Fusion Tables and would like to have the info window pop up when the user searches a country, or selects a country from the selection list.

The map is here: https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/csterling/web/index.html

My goal is to have the info window pop-up when the user selects/searches a country and zooms to that country.

EDIT: I would like the info-window to have the same information as it does when a polygon is clicked.

Comment: What contents do you want in the infoWindow?  Do you want it to behave as if someone clicked on the FusionTablesLayer?  Or some other content?

Comment: I would like it to behave exactly as if someone clicked on the FusionTablesLayer. My apologies for not being clear about that.

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer if you showed the code you've tried but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't know what to do...sorry. I don't have a strong grasp of javascript yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html) which shows how to create infowindows that open from a clickable sidebar.  The infowindow contents is populated with data from a query of the FusionTable using the google visualization library.  Won't be directly applicable, but demonstrates the concept.  You would need to modify the openFtInfoWindow to display your data from your table.

[Here is your map with an infowindow that opens when either the drop down or the text search is used](http://www.geocodezip.com/wisc_edu_csterling_FusionTablesA.html)

Comment: added example using GViz with posted map.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you this works exactly as I hoped. You rock!